# Is Jasper's house in the woods an existing location?

Tags: film-location, children-of-men

In the 2006 film *Children of Men*, Michael Caine's character Jasper lives in a house in the woods.

[image: Jasper's House - Interior]
[image: Jasper's House - Exterior]

1. Is this a real house?
2. Are the interior shots from the same house, or a set?
3. Is the house really in the middle of a wood as depicted in the film?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The house was a set built in the forest of [Bourne Woods, near Farnham in Surrey.](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/c/Children-Of-Men.html#.V6Rck_krKM8)

The location is popular in cinema, and is where the opening battle sequence of *Gladiator* was filmed.

The house was simply a set, and was deconstructed at the end of the shoot.